Blazor .Net 8 login dialog displaying
I'm fairly new to .Net Core/Blazor and have a Blazor .Net 8 web application (server and client applications).  This is an internal application so we are using Windows authentication.  The server application is also the application that serves web api requests.  There are pages that I have set up to be InteractiveWebAssembly with prerendering.  In the client app I have set up a service that performs GETs successfully, but a Windows login dialog is popping up when I do a POST.  This only happens when the application is published to the web server (IIS).  Everything works as it should when running on my PC in development running in Kestrel.  The server website is set up as Windows authentication on/all others off.
Server Program.cs
...            
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
 builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
     options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
 });
...
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAntiforgery();
...

Client Program.cs
...
var apiName = "ServerAPI";
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(apiName, client =>
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress + "api/");
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
});
...

POST call from client service
public async Task<int> SaveRequest(RequestInfoModel model)
{
    using var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Request/saverequest", model);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(resp);
}

Server api controller
[HttpPost("saverequest")]
public async Task<ActionResult<int>> SaveRequest([FromBody] RequestInfoModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
        return BadRequest();

    if (model.RequestID == null)
        return await CreateRequest(model);
    else
        return await UpdateRequest(model);
}

I've tried adding [Authorize] to the api controller thinking maybe that would tell the client to send some extra bits in the request header. I've also tried adding [AllowAnonymous] separately from [Authorize]. Both resulted in the same behavior described above.  In my development I've had neither in the controller. It may also be worth noting that I can perform POSTs from within the generated swagger UI just fine.  There seems to be something amiss specifically with the client app calling the web api. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

but a Windows login dialog is popping up when I do a POST. This only happens when the application is published to the web server (IIS) --> May I know whether you are now working on a blazor wasm app + asp.net core webapi, and the web api is integrating windows auth. Then when you test your app locally, there's never a login popup appearred, but if you host the blazor and api project to IIS, then there will be a login popup window?

Thanks, and yes, this is the new .Net 8 Blazor Web Application that generates a server project and a client project.  I'm using the server project as both my startup project and as the project that provides the web API, which I've read is pretty common to do.  The page I am working on is set to run as WASM, which means it makes calls to the web API to get/save data.  This all works fine when running from Visual Studio in Kestrel.  When I deploy to IIS (on my local pc or on the server), POSTs made from WASM cause a Windows login dialog to be displayed.  GETs work fine.

Thank you for your confirmation, and I'm afraid that your application is a blazor web app auto rendered mode(your solution shall contain a .client and a .server project). Then you integrate windows auth in the .server project. You found that you don't need to enter user name and password in a popup dialog when run the app in VS, but you will have to provide the username and password when host the app in IIS and when you are sending a POST request from the .client project to the .server project. Am I right?

Yes, the only time the login dialog pops up is during a POST.  It doesn't pop up when the application is run or during GETs.  And that only happens when running in IIS.  Also, both GET and POST work fine when tested thru the Swagger UI.

BTW, this page this is occurring on is set up to run as InteractiveWebAssembly.

The issue we are facing now is that the popup credential window only appear for a post request when the app is hosting in IIS. This might related to windows auth not set correctly. If the auth scheme is set correctly, then it might due to the difference between Kestrel and IIS, at least the behavior indicates that, if the auth scheme is set correctly, then Kestrel help to get current windows user credential automatically but IIS doesn't. Since I didn't reproduce your issue, I'm afraid you could share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue.
